# ConText: Extreme Tables: keep row groups together on page break

Tags: context, extreme-tables

Is there a way to keep rowgroups together on a page break (page break before or after group).

In the provided example the page break occurs between B1 and B2. I tried the options split=no but there was no effect. The document is generated and very large. Manually entering a page break is no option.

MWE:

```
\starttext

\dorecurse{18}{text\\\\}

\startxtable[split=yes]
  \startxtablehead
    \startxrow
      \startxcell[nx=2] title \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
  \startxrowgroup[split=no]
    \startxrow
      \startxcell A1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell A1 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell A2 \stopxcell
      \startxcell A2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxrowgroup
  \startxrowgroup[split=no]
    \startxrow
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell B2 \stopxcell
      \startxcell B2 \\\\ B2 \\\\ B2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxrowgroup
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

MWE2: with samepage=after

```
\starttext

\dorecurse{18}{text\\\\}

\startxtable[split=yes]
  \startxtablehead
    \startxrow
      \startxcell[nx=2] title \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \startxrow[samepage=after]
      \startxcell A1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell A1 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell A2 \stopxcell
      \startxcell A2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow[samepage=after]
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
      \startxcell B1 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
    \startxrow
      \startxcell B2 \stopxcell
      \startxcell B2 \\\\ B2 \\\\ B2 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

PS: Can someone explain why it matters to have a empty line between \dorecurse and \startxtable? Otherwise i get a error message and no pdf is build. I thought context doesnt care about free lines.

Comment: To prevent a break between rows you can use the `samepage` key, there is a example in the [xtables manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/show-man-35.htm) on page 10.

Comment: What is the meaning of after, before, both? What do I need to always keep to rows together and allow a split between the groups?

Comment: With `after` you keep the current and the next row together, when you use `before` or `both` you prevent a break between the current and the previous row.

Comment: When I add a [samepage=after] it has no effect, see MWE2

Comment: There is a bug in the current beta which prevents the `samepage` key from working but I already reported this in the ConTeXt list. Another thing is that ConTeXt ignores the settings for the first and last row in a table which means you have to set the `before` value in the second row.